# Datagridview out of range

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want Insert datagridview from database, but I get :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

```
datagridtampil.ColumnCount = 6;
datagridtampil.Columns.Insert(0, cek);
try
{
    string sql = "select * from "+tipe;
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        int j = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                datagridtampil.Rows[j].Cells[i+1].Value = reader[i].ToString();
            }
            j += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: "what's wrong?" - use your debugger!! -> "Index was out of range."

Comment: I mean, what's wrong with my coding ? or my algorithm is wrong ?

Comment: see previous comment...

Comment: c# uses zero-based indices! Cells[i+1] -> 6, but your columns go from 0..5

Comment: because I use columns 0 for checkbox : datagridtampil.Columns.Insert(0, checkbox);

Comment: @MitchWheat this is the first time I use stackoverflow, your previous comment said index was out of range ? so what must I do ?

Comment: I think my problem because I only have 1 row, and my database has 2 rows, so I must add row : datagridtampil.Rows.Add();
but now my datagrid just show last index from database, and the first row is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
datagridtampil.Rows.Clear();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    int j = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        j = datagridtampil.Rows.Add()
        for (int i = 1; i < datagridtampil.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            datagridtampil.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value = reader.GetValue(i-1).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for your answer.....
I think I get error because I not add row. 
can you help me once more ?
how to remove last row on gridview, row that has * on the left

Comment: * Indicates new row which is automatically added when editing finished on last row. If you don't want to add row automatically just set the property `AllowUserToAddRow` to false.